# Workbooks.Open method opens a OneDrive file always in Read only mode

Tags: excel, vba, onedrive

I am using the below code to open a file which is their in OneDrive. However, the file opens always in Read only. I want it to open editable. Could anybody suggest.

```
Dim ObjWbk As Object
Dim Filpath As String
Filepath = Sheet1.Range("F7").Value 'OneDrive file path
Set ObjWbk = Workbooks.Open(Filepath, ReadOnly:=False)
```

Comment: What happens when you open the file with the regular "File->Open"-Dialog in Excel?

Comment: When i manually open file from OneDrive it opens in editable mode

Answer (score 0):

I later came to know that the OneDrive file path should be taken from the details section of a file and not using copy link. Copying the file path from the files details resolved the issue and the file opens editable with the above code.